# Raylib X Collision Response Isn't Working Properly

Tags: c, collision-detection, collision, 2d-games, raylib

I've been making a game with C and Raylib, and I've managed to get the collisions on the Y axis working, but not on the X axis. This is what happens when the player lands on the top of
a rectangle in the game:

[image]

I've tried adjusting the collisions in every way possible, but I still have not gotten it to work. I want the player to be able to move freely on top of the block, and when the player falls off the block, be able to slide down the block but not go through it, just like a normal solid platform block. Currently, the player gets stuck on the edge of the block (as seen from the image), and slides down. Anytime the player tries to land on top of the block, the player gets teleported to the corner (as seen on the image).

Here is my collision code:

```c
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUILDINGS; i++) {
            if (CheckCollisionRecs(playerArea, buildings[i])) {
                DrawText("Collided", 10, 10, 25, BLACK);
            
                //Y COLLISIONS
                if (player.vel.y > 0) {
                    player.pos.y = buildings[i].y - player.height;
                    player.vel.y = 0;
                    player.acc.y = 0;
                    player.canJump = true;
                }

                //X COLLISIONS
                if (player.vel.x < 0) { // If the player moved left and collided with the right side of block
                        player.pos.x = buildings[i].x + buildings[i].width;
                    } else { // If the player moved right and collided with the left side of block
                        player.pos.x = buildings[i].x - player.width;
                    }
                    player.vel.x = 0;
            }
        }
```

I'm just looping through an array of rectangles, called buildings, and then checking collisions for all of them with `buildings[i]`.

Here is my full code if needed:

```c
#include "raylib.h"

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_BUILDINGS 100



int main(void) {

    const int screenWidth = 1600;
    const int screenHeight = 1000;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "Window Title");

    /*---STRUCTS---*/
    typedef struct {
        int FPS;
        int frames;
    } Window;

    Window window = {
        .FPS = 60,
        .frames = 0,
    };

    Rectangle buildings[MAX_BUILDINGS] = { 0 };
    Color buildColors[MAX_BUILDINGS] = { 0 };
    int buildRotation[MAX_BUILDINGS] = { 0 };

    /*---BUILDINGS---*/
    int spacing = screenWidth/2;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUILDINGS; i++) {
        buildings[i].width = (float)GetRandomValue(750, 1000);
        buildings[i].height = screenHeight*2;
        buildings[i].y = (float)GetRandomValue(200, 500);
        buildings[i].x = spacing;

        spacing += (int)buildings[i].width + GetRandomValue(250, 500);

        buildColors[i] = BLUE;
        buildRotation[i] = 0;

    }

    typedef struct {
        float width;
        float height;
        Vector2 pos;
        Vector2 vel;
        Vector2 acc;

        double accSpeed;
        int maxVel;
        double friction;
        double rotation;
        double scale;

        float jumpForce;
        float gravity;
        bool canJump;
    } Player;

    Player player = {
        .width = 50,
        .height = 100,
        .pos = {buildings[0].x + buildings[0].width/2 - player.width/2, buildings[0].y - player.height},
        .vel = {0, 0},
        .acc = {0, 0},

        .accSpeed = 0.15,
        .maxVel = 7,
        .friction = 0.2,
        .rotation = 0,
        .scale = 0.5,

        .jumpForce = 20,
        .gravity = 0.5,
        .canJump = true,
    };

   typedef struct {
        float x;
        float y;
        int speed;
    } Camera;

    Camera cameraPos = {
        .x = screenWidth/2,
        .y = screenHeight/2,
        .speed = 5,
    };

    Camera2D camera = { 0 };
    camera.target = (Vector2) {cameraPos.x, cameraPos.y};
    camera.offset = (Vector2) {screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2};
    camera.rotation = 0.0f;
    camera.zoom = 1.0f;


    SetTargetFPS(window.FPS);

    Rectangle playerArea;

    /*---MAIN GAME LOOP---*/
    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        window.frames++;
        // Update
        if (window.frames >= 3*window.FPS) {
            camera.target.x += cameraPos.speed;
            camera.target.y = player.pos.y;
        }
        playerArea = (Rectangle) {    
            player.pos.x,                
            player.pos.y,                
            player.width,  
            player.height,
        };   
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // TODO: Update your variables here

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUILDINGS; i++) {
            if (CheckCollisionRecs(playerArea, buildings[i])) {
                DrawText("Collided", 10, 10, 25, BLACK);
            
                //Y COLLISIONS
                if (player.vel.y > 0) {
                    player.pos.y = buildings[i].y - player.height;
                    player.vel.y = 0;
                    player.acc.y = 0;
                    player.canJump = true;
                }

                //X COLLISIONS
                if (player.vel.x < 0) { // If the player moved left and collided with the right side of block
                        player.pos.x = buildings[i].x + buildings[i].width;
                    } else { // If the player moved right and collided with the left side of block
                        player.pos.x = buildings[i].x - player.width;
                    }
                    player.vel.x = 0;
            }
        }

        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_LEFT) && player.vel.x > -player.maxVel) {
            player.acc.x = -player.accSpeed;
        } else if (IsKeyDown(KEY_RIGHT) && player.vel.x < player.maxVel) {
            player.acc.x = player.accSpeed;
        } else if (abs(player.vel.x) > 0.2) {
            if (player.vel.x < 0) {
                player.acc.x = player.friction;
            } else {
                player.acc.x = -player.friction;
            }
        } else {
            player.vel.x = 0;
            player.acc.x = 0;
        }
        player.vel.x += player.acc.x;
        player.pos.x += player.vel.x;

            if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_UP) && player.vel.y == 0 && player.acc.y == 0 && player.canJump) {
                player.canJump = false;
                player.vel.y = -player.jumpForce;
            }
        player.acc.y += player.gravity;
        player.vel.y += player.acc.y;
        player.pos.y += player.vel.y;
        player.acc.y = 0;
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Draw
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        BeginDrawing();
            ClearBackground(RAYWHITE); 

            BeginMode2D(camera);  
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUILDINGS; i++) {
                DrawRectanglePro(buildings[i], (Vector2) {0, 0}, buildRotation[i], buildColors[i]);
            }
            DrawRectangle(player.pos.x, player.pos.y, player.width, player.height, RED); 
            EndMode2D();

        EndDrawing();
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CloseWindow();        // Close window and OpenGL context
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    return 0;
}
```

Therefore, **could someone please tell me why the collisions are broken for the X axis?** Is it because of the order of my code in which the collisions are detected? Is my collision logic broken?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where is the CheckCollisionRecs function? You're only showing us your collision response, which doesn't look correct anyway.

Comment: @Phaelaxz, sorry for the confusion, I updated the title because my problem was with the collision response, and I can't figure out what's wrong with my collision response. As for the CheckCollisionRecs function, it is built into the Raylib library.

Comment: What is the response doing that it should not be doing? Hard to guess from just the pic.

Comment: I want the player to be able to move freely on top of the block, and when the player falls off the block, be able to slide down the block but not go through it, just like a normal solid platform block. Currently, the player gets stuck on the edge of the block (as seen from the image), and slides down. Anytime the player tries to land on top of the block, the player gets teleported to the position on the image.

Comment: What I think is happening is, because of gravity you're always colliding with the building. Unless you jump and try to move away before landing on it, it thinks you're in or overlapping the building and thus your collision response is always triggered to reposition the player. You also set the player's Y acceleration to 0, that shouldn't happen unless you hit the building and it stops you from falling. Otherwise, the gravity will be seen as a constant velocity and never accelerate (maybe this was intentional i dont know)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, some basics time. Here you need some maths, but in this case you're trying to make a collision between two rectangles. The formula for them is
`rec1.x < (rec2.x + rec2.width)` and the opposite `rec2.x < (rec1.x + rec1.width)`. And to get the Y collisions you just do it `rec1.y < (rec2.y + rec2.height)` and `rec2.y < (rec1.y + rec1.height)`. After this explanation you should have something along the lines of:

```
if(rec1.x < (rec2.x + rec2.width) && rec2.x < (rec1.x + rec1.width) &&
rec1.y < (rec2.y + rec2.height) && rec2.y < (rec1.y + rec1.height)) collision = true;
```

And after we know we have active collisions for both axis, everything is straight forward.

Note: From my personal experience I made a struct with all the necessary variables.

```
typedef struct GameObject {
    Vector2 position;       // Vector2 contains both X and Y positions
    Vector2 speed;          // Used for speed, can be used in both X and Y axis
    float scale;            // GameObject scale
    Texture2D texture;      // GameOobject texture
    bool canCollide;        //Check if you can collide with a GameObject
    bool hasCollided;       //Check if the GameObject has already collided with something
           
} GameObject;
```

Also, keep in mind that I used textures instead of rectangles, but I represented my GameObjects as rectangles so it's basically the same.

Hope this helped you and wish you all the best!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, but I was actually talking about collision _response_, not necessarily collision detection. If you could provide details on how to do that, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Ok, so when you write your collisions and check if you're colliding with `collision = true`. Then while `collision = true` you either permanently change how an object's physics work or you change them for the period of the collision. Overall, when your collision is true, you do the changes you want.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Collision detection is basically just an algorithm. However, resolution is quite difficult. For example, when the player collides on the X axis, what should I do? Should I cancel the x vel? Should I update a different position? What about the Y axis? Should I cancel out the gravity? These are the questions that I need to have answered.

Comment: You mentioned that your player gets teleported to the top of the building when colliding. I think this might be why `player.pos.x = buildings[i].x + buildings[i].width;`. You set the player's position to top-left where's the building's anchor. You might want to fix that first. Right now I'm a bit busy, but I will make a simple prototype for myself and I will try to solve it.